# Clear cell contents in a data bound datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-c++, datagridview

I am trying to implement a delete functionality in my DataGridView to clear the contents of highlighted cells.

One of the columns contains a double, and when the value is less than zero I display it as blank. If the user edits the cell to blank, this is handled via the CellParsing event.

The DataGridView is databound using a BindingSource and BindingList.

The issue I'm having is that when I change the cell Value to blank via my clear function, the CellParsing event does not fire and I get a FormatException saying that "" is not a valid value for Double. When the user clears the cell, the CellParsing event fires and everything happens as expected.

The reason I am setting the value to blank is that some of the columns are text and others are numbers, and I'd like to be able to delete them all at once.

I've googled and searched through StackOverflow and haven't found something yet that will solve my issue. Is there a way to route this through the CellParsing event or some other obvious solution that I'm missing?

See the CellParsing and clearing code below.

```
System::Void dataGridViewWells_CellParsing(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::DataGridViewCellParsingEventArgs^  e)
{
    //Handle blank values in the mass column
    e->ParsingApplied = false;
    if(this->dataGridViewWells->Columns[e->ColumnIndex]->HeaderText == "Mass (ng)")
    {
        if(e->Value->ToString() == "" || e->Value->ToString() == " ")
        {
            e->Value = -1.0;
            e->ParsingApplied = true;
        }
    }
}

void DeleteHighlightedCells(DataGridView^ dgv)
{
    try
    {
        System::Windows::Forms::DataGridViewSelectedCellCollection^ sCells = dgv->SelectedCells;
        for(int i = 0; i < sCells->Count; i++)
        {
            if(!sCells[i]->ReadOnly)
            {
                dgv->Rows[sCells[i]->RowIndex]->Cells[sCells[i]->ColumnIndex]->Value = "";
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception^ e)
    {
        LogError("Unable to delete contents of DataGridView cells: " + e->ToString());
    }
}

System::Void dataGridViewWells_KeyDown(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::KeyEventArgs^  e)
{
    if(e->Control && e->KeyCode == Keys::C)
    {
        this->CopyContentsToClipBoard(this->dataGridViewWells);
    }

    if(e->Control && e->KeyCode == Keys::V)
    {
        this->PasteContentsFromClipBoard(this->dataGridViewWells);
    }

    if(e->KeyCode == Keys::Delete)
    {
        this->DeleteHighlightedCells(this->dataGridViewWells);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up abandoning the CellParsing event and putting in a custom TypeConverter for my class property as was done in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634643/datagridview-binding).

TypeConverter code:

```
public ref class MassTypeConverter : System::ComponentModel::TypeConverter
{
public:
    virtual bool CanConvertFrom(System::ComponentModel::ITypeDescriptorContext^ context, Type^ sourceType) override
    {
        return sourceType == String::typeid || System::ComponentModel::TypeConverter::CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }
    virtual Object^ ConvertFrom(System::ComponentModel::ITypeDescriptorContext^ context, System::Globalization::CultureInfo^ culture, Object^ value) override
    {
        if(value != nullptr && value->GetType() == String::typeid)
        {
            //
            double converted;
            bool success = double::TryParse((String^)value, converted);
            if(((String^)value) == "" || ((String^)value) == " ")
            {
                converted = -1.0;
                success = true;
            }
            if(success)
            {
                return converted;
            }
        }
        return System::ComponentModel::TypeConverter::ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }
};
```

And then put the following above my class Property:

```
[System::ComponentModel::TypeConverter(MassTypeConverter::typeid)]
```